# Split nested lists into different lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, nested-lists

I have a list like this:

```
list1=[['xx', 'xx', 'xx', 'xx', 'xx'],
 ['yy', 'yy', 'yy', 'yy', 'yy'],
 ['zz',
  'zz',
  'zz',
  'zz',
  'zz',
  'zz',
  'zz',
  'zz',
  'zz'],
 ['tt', 'tt', 'tt', 'tt', 'tt']
.
.
.
n]
```

I would like to have a method to cast the nested lists into different lists. However, as the length of `list1` differs every time my program executes I want to have an automated procedure

For example, the expected outcome looks like that.

```
list1= ['xx', 'xx', 'xx', 'xx', 'xx']
list2= ['yy', 'yy', 'yy', 'yy', 'yy', 'yy']
list3= ['zz', 'zz', 'zz', 'zz', 'zz', 'zz', 'zz', 'zz', 'zz']
list4= ['tt', 'tt', 'tt', 'tt', 'tt']
.
.
.
listn=[...........]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like XY problem. The lists are already different, why do you need them in different variables?

Comment: Why can't you access the inner lists as `list1[i]`?

Comment: @Psytho is for a semantic similarity problem and I want to have separate their embeddings

Comment: How will the rest of your script refer to `listn` if you don't know whether it will exist?

Comment: @PeterWood the essence of my question is that list1  sometimes is a nested list of length 4, sometimes of length 3 and sometimes of length n. The length change each time

Comment: what you are trying to do is simply wrong. If you don't know, at coding time, if there will be a `list4`, how could you have code that would use the  `list4` variable?  
Variable size content is what list (and other containers, such as dictionaries) are for. Keeping the lists nested you can easily know how many there are with `len(list1)`.

Comment: @jsbueno let's avoid fancy expressions such as "simply wrong" or whatever else. It is just a question. Saying that, Perhaps a procedure that goes to the end of the nested list -1 will do the trick

Comment: @xavi why do you need `list45`, `list46`, `list47` to be defined in your script if they're not going to be used? How far up would it go, `list1000`? How would you use them anyway? If it's not "simply wrong" it's at least very badly conceived.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good practice at all Use list[index] to get the list at any position, Like use list[45] to get the list at index 45.

but if you want then you can use this code.

Try this

```
full_list=[['xx', 'xx', 'xx', 'xx', 'xx'],
 ['yy', 'yy', 'yy', 'yy', 'yy'],
 ['zz',
  'zz',
  'zz',
  'zz',
  'zz',
  'zz',
  'zz',
  'zz',
  'zz'],
 ['tt', 'tt', 'tt', 'tt', 'tt']]

allListName = []
for i in range(1,len(full_list)+1):
    exec(f"list{i}={full_list[i-1]}")
    allListName.append(f'list{i}')
print(allListName)
print(list1)
print(list2)
# print(listn)
```

OUTPUT

```
['list0', 'list1', 'list2', 'list3']
['yy', 'yy', 'yy', 'yy', 'yy']
['zz', 'zz', 'zz', 'zz', 'zz', 'zz', 'zz', 'zz', 'zz']
```

---

1. In the loop `i` is the index of the list in the `full_list` and the `list[i]` is the list at the `i` index.
2. `exec` function run string as a code block so the in this case string is  `f'list{i}={list[i]}'` so this string is executed as a string.
3. if i is 1 then `list1=['xx', 'xx', 'xx', 'xx', 'xx']` and soon.
4. For the `allListName` this contains all the nested list names that are created in the loop.
5. If you want all nested names with the value to print then use this code below the loop.

```py
for an in allListName:
    print(f'{a} = {locals()[a]}')
```

Output

```
list1 = ['xx', 'xx', 'xx', 'xx', 'xx']
list2 = ['yy', 'yy', 'yy', 'yy', 'yy']
list3 = ['zz', 'zz', 'zz', 'zz', 'zz', 'zz', 'zz', 'zz', 'zz']
list4 = ['tt', 'tt', 'tt', 'tt', 'tt']
```

Comment: What's the output?

Comment: this will work, but since you bothered to answer, it would be nice to explain the O.P. that this it is not a good idea at all, as the created variables simply can't be used in a meaningful way in normal code.

Comment: @jsbueno Sorry, I have to go to some school work that's why I only post the code. Now I add some explanation hope this will help.